# How to optimize complex SQL quests with windowing?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get first two transactions per user per day, and then I need to sum transaction amounts per user.

Here is Transactions table:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
  transaction_id INT,
  user_id INT,
  amount DECIMAL(5,2),
  ts TIMESTAMP
);
```

My solution:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    SUM(amount)
FROM (
  SELECT 
      tx.transaction_id,
      tx.user_id,
      tx.amount,
      rnk.tx_rank
  FROM Transactions AS tx JOIN (
      SELECT
          transaction_id,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', ts) ASC) AS tx_rank
      FROM Transactions
  ) AS rnk 
  ON tx.transaction_id = rnk.transaction_id
  WHERE tx_rank < 3
) AS s GROUP BY user_id;
```

I need to optimize the quesry. What can be possible direction how to do that?

Comment: Can you tag which SQL server and version you are using.

Comment: Your query does not do what you are asking.  It is adding up *all* transactions from the first two days in the data for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think this will be better:

```
SELECT tx.user_id, SUM(tx.amount)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE_TRUNC('day', ts) ORDER BY ts ASC) AS seqnum
      FROM Transactions t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum < = 2
GROUP BY user_id;
```

In addition, this should be accurate as well.  Your code is only adding values together for the first two days a user has transactions, not the "first two transactions per user per day".